# Generate a table of contents to have PDF outlines, but don't show it?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf

Is there a way to generate a table of contents without showing it?

I am using sections and a table of contents to generate an outline in a pdf document, but I would prefer the table of contents not be shown.

Is there a way to solve this?

My document at the moment:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksdepth=5]{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=1, 
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines
}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Other section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Um, `%\tableofcontents`?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Teepeemm commenting out the table of contents will mean no table of contents is generated. I want to generate one, as I need it to display outlines in the PDF file. I just don't want the table of contents to be visible. If there is a way to have outlines in the PDF file without generate a table of contents, that would work also.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Comment: @Teepeemm: Please post your comment as an aswer as that is exactly what the OP wanted as per the commens in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, hyperref writes the toc entries to the pdf outline, so leaving out `\tableofcontents` will work just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\section{Other section}
\end{document}
```

The complicating thing is that for various TeX reasons, anytime you're dealing with a table of contents, you might need to compile two (or three or four) times before being done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean by display the outlines, but here is a solution hides the content of the TOC

#### Original

[image]

#### After Applying `\RedefineToc`

[image]

If you want just a blank page you can instead comment out the following line

```
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{}%
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksdepth=5]{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=1, 
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines
}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\newcommand*{\RedefineToc}{%
    \let\OldContentsLine\contentsline
    \renewcommand\contentsline[4]{\OldContentsLine{##1}{Xx}{##3}{##4}}%
   %\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{}% <-- Uncomment to get blank page
}%

\begin{document}
{\RedefineToc%
\tableofcontents
}%
\newpage
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{Other section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For me this displays a page that says Contents, with no TOC entries, even after uncommenting the line you say will give a blank page. Is there a way to just have no page instead of a blank page? By outlines I mean the navigation entries shown in a PDF view, here is a screengrab showing the chrome PDF viewer: https://imgur.com/a/CBXuhcl

Comment: If you just want the bookmarks, then commenting out the `\tableofcontents` won't print the TOC and yet still provide the bookmarks. You just need to run it twice (just like you have to do with `\tableofcontents`) to get the bookmarks.

Comment: Oh that worked a treat! If you want to make that the answer I will accept...it never would have occurred to me to comment it and run it twice. I don't understand why that works at all, but if it's a silly question happy to delete the question instead.

Comment: @KenRogers: No worries. Things with LaTeX are often not obvious, so don't be afraind to ask. I have asked quite a few embarrasing ones on this site, so I undestandl. But you won't be the last person to have this issue.  I have asked Teepeemm to post an answer as that comment actually solved the problem for you, not me.

Comment: `\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}` produces the bookmarks, using the `\section{...}` etc commands. `\tableofcontents` is not required for the bookmarks.

Comment: Text can be 'hidden' (i.e., glyphs not stroked and filled) with pdf literals, e.g., in xelatex: `\special{pdf:literal direct q 3 Tr}%
any text \special{pdf:literal direct Q}`. `q` and `Q` are store and restore the graphic state; `3 Tr` is "text rendering mode 3: no stroke and no fill".

Comment: Thank you Peter Grill and @Cicada